# Network sniffer that work as windows service

Tags: windows, networking, packet-capture

We need to log the traffic of incoming traffic for some application on our server.

The first instinct is to use Wireshark and of course, as soon our remote session end Wireshark also shutdown. 
Since we need to capture the data over a long period of time (1-2 day) we cannot leave the session open so long.

Any software that can perform network logging that runs as a windows service?

The server in question runs windows server 2016

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can [run a program as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable) but in your case, I would consider running Wireshark as a scheduled task with the right [arguments](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html).